# How do I create an instance of a search plugin?

Tags: 8, search, plugins

I created a custom search plugin to index and search a sub-set of taxonomy terms and their fields, as these are used as landing pages. In addition, we are using the node search. This gives us two search pages, which both work.

However, taking inspiration from the Drupal 7 search_combine module, we want to create a page with the combined search result.

So we set out to create another search plugin in a custom module. This gets all active search pages and their IDs. So far so good. Now the idea is that this plugins execute method goes through all active search pages, creates an instance of the respective search plugin, gets the results of that search using plugin->execute(), and combines the result arrays and then returns the combined search results (pretty much as search_combine does for Drupal 7).

However, we are having problems following the instructions [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/plugin_api/8.2.x#sec_use).

Here are the steps to follow to perform a task that involves plugins:
- Locate the machine name of the plugin manager service, and instantiate the service. See the Services topic for more information on how to do this.
- On the plugin manager class, use methods like `getDefinition()`, `getDefinitions()`, or other methods specific to particular plugin managers to retrieve information about either specific plugins or the entire list of defined plugins.
- Call the `createInstance()` method on the plugin manager to instantiate individual plugin objects.
- Call methods on the plugin objects to perform the desired tasks.

Our service is "[plugin.manager.search](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!search!src!SearchPluginManager.php/class/SearchPluginManager/8.2.x)", if I am not mistaken.

However, I am a bit puzzled by the rest. How do we now use this to get the respective plugin definitions and then create an instance of that plugin?

Comment: To answer my own question:

`code`$search_services = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.search');
$search_services->createInstance($plugin_id, $configuration);`code`

In my case, $configuration is an empty array.

Comment: While now I can call each plugins execute method, these seem to return paged results. So I would need to get rid of the pagers and get all combined results, and then page them again...